# How is it possible map the polyhedron of interval coefficients in polynamial using Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Here there is a interval polynomial in **s** domain and the coefficients of **s** terms are defined in specific domain.

[image]

How is it possible to **map the polyhedron of interval coefficients in polynamial**? (In existence of these interval?)

Here is a plot but how?

[image]

Comment: How do you expect the output to look like? I assume this results in either a surface or multiple lines in a `rlocus` plot

Comment: Okay the output is clear now, a final quest. Is this the expected output for your transfer function or just some random example? If the later, do you have the transfer function as well?

Comment: Its the interval characteristic polynomial of the system (T = G/(G+1)) and the above polynomial = (G+1) part of T.Unfortunately I don't have G .

Comment: I think this plot refers to roots of this interval polynomial .It's better to plot its roots..Any suggestion to plot the roots?

Comment: I think salam is correct

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a single-input-multiple-output (SIMO) system where the brackets in your question denote two transfer functions, then you need to plot a root locus for both of the outputs individually.

First, create the whole transfer function:

```
>> s = tf('s');
>> H = [0.07;0.09]*s^4 + [0.45;0.94]*s^3 + [1.1;1.5]*s^2 + [0.887;1.487]*s +0.3

H =

  From input to output...
   1:  0.07 s^4 + 0.45 s^3 + 1.1 s^2 + 0.887 s + 0.3

   2:  0.09 s^4 + 0.94 s^3 + 1.5 s^2 + 1.487 s + 0.3

Continuous-time transfer function.
```

After you can plot them individually with [`rlocus`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/rlocus.html):

```
figure;
subplot(1,2,1);
rlocus(H(1)); title('output 1');
subplot(1,2,2);
rlocus(H(2)); title('output 2');
```

[image: result]

Comment: You would have to do something like that for all 64 edges of the 4D box defined by the coefficient intervals to get the image in the question. -- Your homotopy follows a main diagonal of that box

Answer (score 2):

If you plot the interval polynomial roots :

```
e = 0.3;
for a = 0.07 : 0.09 : 0.09
    for b = 0.45:0.09:0.49;
        for c = 1.1:0.09:1.5;
            for d = 0.887:0.09:1.487
Roots = roots([a b c d e])
plot(Roots,'s')
hold on
            end
        end
    end
end
grid;
```

the roots plot :

[image]

Similar but not 3D as you want.

I saw this 3D form in mapping the polyhedron of coefficients:

[image]